# 'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'ls_files'

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the function ls_files from BlobServiceClient library found in this github (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_directory_interface.py). However, when I ran the code, I get an error:

'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'ls_files'

Here is my code:

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, PublicAccess, __version__
from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService
import re

account_name = ACCOUNT_NAME
account_key = ACCOUNT_KEY
connect_str = CONNECTION_STRING
account_url = ACCOUNT_URL
container_name = CONTAINER_NAME
file_path = FILE_PATH
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name = account_name, account_key = account_key)
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url = account_url, connect_str = connect_str, container_name = container_name)

def list_filenames_in_blob(blob):
    file_names = blob_service_client.ls_files(file_path)
    return file_names

def run_action():
    try:
       for blob in generator:
            list_filenames_in_blob(blob)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_action()
```

Could you please let me know what I did wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `BlobServiceClient` in the python package does not have the method `ls_files`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python). we need to implement it by ourselves. In the document, you refer to, [the user also does that](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/32bfb29b0ed5f22ded9008c1533b7e9ae734978b/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_directory_interface.py#L107).

Besides, according to my understanding, we want to list all the names of the blobs in one storage container. If so, please refer to the following code

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

conn_str = ''
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)

blob_list = blob_service_client.get_container_client('<container name>').list_blobs()

for blob in blob_list:
    print(blob.name)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Jim Xu for your reply. I did followed another Microsoft tutorial and I resolved my issue.

Comment: so, which Microsoft tutorial you followed @Shuti to resolve the issue?